# How to evaluate value of a variable in Json Key in Karate?

Tags: karate

I have a request Json for one of my API calls, where the Key of Json Object itself is a variable which needs to be evaluated while hitting the API.
Normally when i have to use variable in Json, I simply use #(varName) and it works fine as long as I am having this as Json Value. 
I want to do the same for Json Key.

Sample json snippet is:-

```
"Registrations": {
   "#(varName)": {
   "requestedAction": "REGISTER",
   "productId": "#(varName)",
   "registrationSourceType": "Selected",
   "includedInAgenda": false
   }`
```

In above example, Registration Json block has nested Json where my KeyName will be an uuid.

Answer (score 2):

Just use JS:

```
* def myJson = { registrations: {} }
* def uuid = 'someString'
* myJson.registrations[uuid] = { foo: 'bar' }
* match myJson == { registrations: { someString: { foo: 'bar' } } }
```